# Maven Jetty logback issue

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I'm using Maven with the Jetty plugin. When I use `mvn jetty:run`, I get the error below:

```
2016-06-28 10:45:30.550:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.8.v20150217
2016-06-28 10:45:39.403:INFO:/:main: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2016-06-28 10:45:39.418:INFO:/:main: Set web app root system property: 'base' = [D:\code\project-new\project\src\main\webapp]
2016-06-28 10:45:39.460:INFO:/:main: Initializing Logback from [classpath:/config/logback/logback.xml]
2016-06-28 10:45:39.467:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@6b270743{/,file:/D:/code/project-new/project/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/D:/code/project-new/project/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
```

Jetty plugin in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.8.v20150217</version>
</plugin>
```

logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p [%c] [%t] - &lt;%m&gt;%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="logfile"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${catalina.home}/logs/base.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p [%c] [%t] - &lt;%m&gt;%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/logs/base.log.%d{.yyyy-MM-dd}
            </fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.springframework" level="WARN"/>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        <appender-ref ref="logfile"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I have tried a few methods, but still can't solve this problem.